# Socratic badge meaning

Tags: support, badges

I don't understand what the this definition - part of the [gold Socratic badge](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/91/socratic) - means :

"Ask a well-received question on 100 separate days, and maintain a positive question record".

Comment: @CarLaTeX thank you anyway.

Comment: You're welcome! (I deleted my answer). :):):)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a full description of the entire badge family:

#### Curious

- bronze; awarded once
- Asked a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintained a positive question record

#### Inquisitive

- silver; awarded once
- Asked a well-received question on 30 separate days, and maintained a positive question record

#### Socratic

- gold; awarded multiple times
- Asked a well-received question on 100 separate days, and maintained a positive question record

**Additional criteria for this badge family:**

- There are four different counts that are tracked when calculating the criteria for this badge:

  - Positive: Number of questions asked on this day that have a score greater than 0.
  - Negative: Number of questions asked on this day that have a score less than 0.
  - Closed: Number of questions asked on this day that are currently closed and the current closure date occurred within 60 days of being asked.
  - Deleted: Number of questions asked on this day that are currently deleted and the current deletion date occurred within 60 days of being asked.
- Any day that has at least 1 Positive question and also has no Negative, Closed, or Deleted questions counts as a GoodDay which increments the counter.
- A positive question record means you don't have too many closed, downvoted or deleted questions, overall. The formula is `(TotalQuestions - Negative - Closed - Deleted) / TotalQuestions ≥ 0.5`. Questions that qualify as Negative *and* Closed *and* Deleted count three times in this calculation!

Reference:

[List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/168244)

Comment: I haven't no clue about the full description list.